# Browser White Space and Extra Lines Caused by Php and Wordpress

Tags: php, html, wordpress, whitespace

When I view the source of my webpage in the browser, I see a lot of white space around one section of the page.  I can't seem to prevent this.  Below is the code I am using.

The function that is called in html page:

```
function query_single($posttype, $poststatus, $paidvalue, $taxtype, $value) {

/* Custom Query for a state, county, or city to display dentist with a single taxonomy query. This displays the results of the loop in taxonomy-dealercity.php, taxonomy-dealerstate.php, taxonomy-dealercounty.php, taxonomy-auctioncity.php, taxonomy-auctionstate.php, taxonomy-auctioncounty.php */

global $wp_query;
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
 $args = array(
   'post_type' => $posttype,
   'post_status' => array($poststatus),
   'orderby' => 'rand', 
   'posts_per_page' => 30,
   'meta_query' => array(
      array(
          'key' => 'wpcf-paid',
          'value' => array($paidvalue),
          'compare' => 'IN',
      )
  ),
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => $taxtype,
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $value
        )
    )
);
return $wp_query->query($args);
}
```

The taxonomy-state.php page with html and php:

```
<div class="co7">
 <?php /*Based on type of page a custom h1 and page text is shown*/

 echo "<h1 class=\"title\">$geo_no_dash Destist - Find a Dentist in $geo_no_dash</h1>";

 echo "<p><small>Search for Dentist in $geo_no_dash with our comprehensive $geo_no_dash    Dentist catalog. Find a Dentist in $geo_no_dash by city, state, county</small></p>";?>

 <?php
 /* This function found in the themes function.php file gets dentist which are used in   the first wordpress loop which will show only paid dentist. */

query_single('dealers', 'publish', '1', $taxtype, $value);
 ?>

 <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
 <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

 <?php /* Retrieve relevant dentist information with get_post_meta.  Function   get_dealer_brands gets each dentist brands via a function added in the theme function.php file.  Last section echos out dentist listings.*/

 $address=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-street_address', TRUE); 
 $city=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-city', TRUE); 
 $state=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-state_abbreviation', TRUE); 
 $zip=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-zip_code', TRUE); 
 $phone=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-phone_number', TRUE); 
 $paid=get_post_meta($post->ID, 'wpcf-paid', TRUE);
 get_each_dealer_brand()?>

 <ul class="ullisting">
 <?php if($paid==1)
 {
echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\"><strong><a href=\"";the_permalink(); echo "\">";the_title();echo "</a></strong></p></li>";
echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">$address | $city, $state $zip</p></li>";
echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">P: $phone</p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"listing\"><span><small>$brands_list</small></span></p></li>";
}?>
</ul>
```

The browser white space is between each  `ul class="ullisting` and is 4 to 7 rows of white space when viewing the source in the browser.

I am rebuilding my install of wordpress so i don't have an live example right now.  But here is the output I was gettting:

```
<pre><code>

 <!--Start Side Left Co7-->

 <div class="co7">
 <h1 class="title">Texas Dentist - Find Dentist in Texas</h1><p><small>Search for a Dentist in Texas with our comprehensive Dentist catalog.</small></p>



<ul class="ullisting">
<li><p class="plisting"><strong><a href="http://www.test.com/dealers/dentist1/">Dentist  1</a></strong></p></li><li><p class="plisting">g | g, g g</p></li><li><p class="plisting">P: h</p></li><li><p class="listing"><span><small>Gosmile</small></span> </p></li></ul>







<ul class="ullisting">
<li><p class="plisting"><strong>Dentist 2</strong></p></li><li><p class="plisting">26 main | Spring, TX 77090</p></li><li><p class="plisting">P: 7146122454</p></li><li><p class="listing"><span><small>Brightsmile</small></span></p></li></ul>



<ul class="ullisting">
<li><p class="plisting"><strong>Dentist 3</strong></p></li><li><p class="plisting">35 Main st | Houston, Tx 777090</p></li><li><p class="plisting">P: 1</p></li><li><p class="listing"><span><small>Pro Whitening</small></span></p></li></ul>
```

Comment: Is there a link we can view the example containing the white space?

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you drop out of PHP like you are, those line breaks will be sent out to the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespace is no big deal. But if it means that much to you, do the following.  Change this code:

```
 <ul class="ullisting">
 <?php if($paid==1)
 {
echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\"><strong><a href=\"";the_permalink(); echo "\">";the_title();echo "</a></strong></p></li>";
echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">$address | $city, $state $zip</p></li>";
echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">P: $phone</p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"listing\"><span><small>$brands_list</small></span></p></li>";
}?>
</ul>
```

To this:

```
<?php 
echo "<ul class="ullisting">";
 if($paid==1)
 {
echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\"><strong><a href=\"";the_permalink(); echo "\">";the_title();echo "</a></strong></p></li>";
echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">$address | $city, $state $zip</p></li>";
echo "<li><p class=\"plisting\">P: $phone</p></li>";
    echo "<li><p class=\"listing\"><span><small>$brands_list</small></span></p></li>";
}

echo "</ul>";
?>
```

The issue seems to be that since you have a page where there are pure HTML elements mixed with php code to "echo" conetent, then just force PHP to echo the content so you know that the spacing is to your liking.

But in general, I live with spacing issues like that since that is a side effect of coding that way anyway; it won’t ever be pure unless you go completely OCD on the line spacing & I don’t find it to be worth the effort.